# How to get value in a textbox from a JSF page to a Java Class?

Tags: jsf-2

I already created the bean, and it gets the value from the textbox, my problem is how can i pass it to another java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it as method argument the usual Java way. You can do it in the action method.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
private String input; // +getter +setter

public void submit() {
    YourAnotherClass yourAnotherClass = new YourAnotherClass();
    yourAnotherClass.process(input);
}
```